# ARM 20-pin JTAG header?

Tags: arm, jtag

I'm trying to find the JTAG header for an Intel X Scale (ArmV5) PXA270 board. I found and populated a 20-pin header:

[image: ARM JTAG 20-pin header]

but JTAGulator doesn't think it has a valid combination of TDI/TDO/TMS/TCK on either a IDCode or bypass scan. I put a logic analyzer on it and don't really see a steady clock:

[image: logic analyzer 20-pin jtag]

Is it possible the clock is elsewhere and some of the header pins are still TDI/TDO etc., or do any of the logic analyzer data seem they could be from JTAG?

Comment: Are there other headers/pads?

Comment: Maybe its domek kind of serial communication interface (UART).

Comment: does it have >5 GND pins in  a row? if not, it might be not JTAG but flash or similar

Comment: The JTAGulator has a UART option I can check, but does this look like UART data or something else? It doesn't have the whole row of GND (or 9 pins anyway), which is what I was expecting. I should still see a steady clock, right?